# .NET Core - Some concept of IHost.StartAsync()

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am study for dotnet core just begin.
And there are some concepts make me confused. I want to clarify it.
So what *host.StartAsync()* do in the runtime? Will it keep running a while loop in background to execute some code created by event or request ?

Comment: Have a look at specs for [generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#startasync)

Comment: The compiler doesn't run your code... are you asking what the runtime will do when running `host.StartAsync()`?

Comment: @GeoffJames thanks for your reply !
Yes I will like to know in the runtime. The console shows similar with a infinite loop.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes , but it is more confuse me. So as I know, a Task is represent a work that will be done.When it encounter await key word, it will wait for the Task finish and continue doing the following thing.But the document says "returns a Task that completes when the cancellation token or shutdown is triggered." is that mean the Task will be done when the cancellation token or shutdown is triggered ? If yes, when it pass the await It's mean the host is shut down, if not, it's mean it will never pass await key word.